# Similar plugin filter results by section

Tags: templating, plugins

I currently have the [Similar](https://nystudio107.com/docs/similar) plugin on my system, and I'm looking for similar entries by Category. It's working great, but I'm looking to limit the results to a specific section.

```
    {% set limitCriteria = craft.entries().section('merchants').limit(4) %}
    {% set similarEntriesByCat = craft.similar.find({ element: entry, context: entry.vertical, criteria: limitCriteria }) %}

    <ul>
    {% for similarEntry in similarEntriesByCat %}
        <li>{{ similarEntry.title }} ({{ similarEntry.count }} tags in common)</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But the above code returns the following database error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'structureelements.structureId' in 'group statement' The SQL being
> executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements_sites`.`siteId`,
> COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`,
> `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS
> `contentId` FROM `elements` `elements`

Unsure how to fix the above?

Comment: Looks like there's already a GH issue for this: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-similar/issues/22

Comment: You're right Brad! Thanks for answering.